# jQuery function to create table using JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

How do you retrieve a JSON object from a local file and display it in a table using jQuery? Here is the content of JSON file (`jsondata.json`):

```
{
"scores" : [ ["3/1/2011", 610],["4/1/2011", 610],["5/1/2011", 610],["6/1/2011", 610], ["7/1/2011", 720], ["8/1/2011", 500], ["9/1/2011", 500] ]
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Example - Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kVdZG/

You can iterate and append the elements.

```
<table id='scores' border="1"></table>
```

JS -

```
var data = { "scores" : [ ["3/1/2011", 610],["4/1/2011", 610],["5/1/2011", 610],["6/1/2011", 610], ["7/1/2011", 720], ["8/1/2011", 500], ["9/1/2011", 500] ] }


$(data.scores).each(function(index, element){  
     $('#scores').append('<tr><td> '+element[0]+' </td> <td> '+element[1]+' </td></tr>');       
})
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not provide any function to format JSON as a HTML table. jQuery provides only the functionality required to itterate the JSON object and manipulate the DOM. However, there are jQuery plugins that can do that.

https://github.com/gajus/json-to-table

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: This works best and you don't need jQuery:
https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table

Answer (score -1):

```
var json = { "scores" : [ ["3/1/2011", 610],["4/1/2011", 610],["5/1/2011", 610],["6/1/2011", 610], ["7/1/2011", 720], ["8/1/2011", 500], ["9/1/2011", 500] ] }

    $.each(json.scores,function(key,value){

        alert(key + " "+value)
    })
```

u can check from here http://jsfiddle.net/atMa7/

Comment: Console.log maybe better than the alert?

Comment: Or neither, since the question asks the data to be presented in a table.