# Best way to create grid from JSON data which dynamically resizes based on number of entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple JSON like so:

> [{"NAME":"Bill","Score":25,"URL":"Bill.html"},{"NAME":"Jane","Score":16,"URL":"Jane.html"},{"NAME":"Xavier","Score":5,"URL":"Xavier.html"},{"NAME":"Hector","Score":32,"URL":"Hector.html"}]

The actual JSON has many more records.  I would like to display all the records on a page like so:

1) In a grid (boxes, no title rows, only the NAME and SCORE appearing in each box and when clicking on the box takes you to the URL).
2) As people's names are added to the JSON, the grid will automatically resize each box to allow for new boxes for the new names - the grid always uses up 100% of the width and height of the parent div

So, if there were only two names in the JSON, the screen would be split in half (horizontally or vertically).  If there were three names in the JSON, there would be three boxes (each using 1/3 of the div).  Four would have two rows and two columns, etc... The actual JSON will have at least 50 records, so maybe 9 columns and 6 rows (empty cells would be at the bottom right) but could end up having 200 records (in which case the boxes would dynamically shrink to allow for needed space).

Essentially I'm hoping for some kind of plugin which could create this grid with a dataset with as few records as 10, but as large as 500.

I'm not sure if I'm being very clear...I've been reading up on JQuery templates, I also ran across these:

- http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/04/json-objects-to-html-table
- [jQuery function to create table using JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803171/jquery-function-to-create-table-using-json-data)
- http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/Editing/JSONCRUD
- http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/json-jquery-ajax-php.html

I'm not sure which is the best approach, or if there is an even easier approach.  I'd really appreciate any advice you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

It is too simple to configure

```
$('#container').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector : '.item',
  layoutMode : 'fitRows'
});
```

Comment: That looks pretty awesome Wolf.  Could be exactly what I hoped for.  Will look at it more.  Thanks a lot