# JSON, converting to HTML to use with Isotope.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

UPDATE:  I have changed this question around.  I was unable to figure it out, even though I'm sure I got two great answers.  I have tried to simplify this question so I can figure it out in a more methodical manner.  I hope this can help other newbs like myself...

I would like to use isotope.js to display selected data from a JSON (this question is related to the question I posted here):

[Best way to create grid from JSON data which dynamically resizes based on number of entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146526/best-way-to-create-grid-from-json-data-which-dynamically-resizes-based-on-number)

I've been reading about isotope today (I'm also a newbie to Javascript), and I'm sure this question will seem elementary to a lot of you.  Anyways here goes...

From what I see, I need to have the html in this format to feed to isotope (this is taken from the basic example on isotope found here - https://github.com/DaweiCheng/isotope-tutorial/blob/master/basic.html):

```
<div class="element other nonmetal   " data-symbol="H" data-category="other">
      <p class="number">1</p>
      <h3 class="symbol">H</h3>
      <h2 class="name">Hydrogen</h2>
      <p class="weight">1.00794</p>
    </div>
```

So, if I had a JSON like so (please assume multiple records that are similar):

```
[{"name":"Hydrogen","number":1,"symbol":"H","weight":1.00794},{"name":"Helium","number":2,"symbol":"He","weight":4.002602},{"name":"Lithium","number":3,"symbol":"Li","weight":6.941},{"name":"Beryllium","number":4,"symbol":"Be","weight":9.012182},{"name":"Boron","number":5,"symbol":"B","weight":10.811},...]
```

*Please note that any fields that are numbers in the JSON are integers, not strings.

I want to turn the JSON into this:

```
<div id="container">

<div class="element">
<p class="number">1</p>
<h3 class="symbol">H</h3>
<h2 class="name">Hydrogen</h2>
<p class="weight">1.00794</p>
</div>
<div class="element">
...
</div>

</div>
```

How would I convert the JSON into the required HTML?

To make things simple (for me), I want the div class for each record to always be element (so as I learn to change isotope, I can initially begin by using the css from their tutorials).  The container div doesn't need to be repeated for each record, all the records will be displayed within the container (I guess that doesn't need saying)...

I have tried doing it using the answers below (which answer how I previously asked this question), however when doing so I either got nothing returned (and no errors in the console), or I got what appears like an empty table cell.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm very sorry to the two users who responded, I'm thankful for your help and I'll continue to play with your answers in the hope I figure it out.

Comment: added jsfiddle to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function whose role is to accept the result from your Ajax and it iterates over every object, grabs the requisite data from it and outputs a div with the needed information.

For example:

```
function renderUser(ajaxResponse) {

    // turn string response to JSON array
    var responseArray = JSON.parse(ajaxResponse);

    // make sure there is a response
    if (responseArray.length > 0) {

        // get container
        var container = document.getElementById("container");

        // iterate over each response
        for (var i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i += 1) {

            // create the elems needed
            var player = document.createElement("div");
            player.className = "players";
            player.data-Name = responseArray[i].name;

            var score = document.createElement("p");
            score.className = "score";
            score.innerHTML = responseArray[i].score;

            var name = document.createElement("h3");
            name.className = "name";
            name.innerHTML = responseArray[i].name;

            var city= document.createElement("p");
            city.className = "city";
            city.innerHTML = responseArray[i].city;

            // append them all to player wrapper
            player.appendChild(score);
            player.appendChild(name);
            player.appendChild(city);

            // append player to container
            container.appendChild(player);
        }
    } 
}
```

edit:

Took the liberty of making a fiddle to do exactly what you wanted here: http://jsfiddle.net/92FgL/

Comment: Thanks, could you check my update and let me know if that's what you mean?  I would then just update my css with the proper classes and it should work?  I'm a little confused as to what goes in the html body tag apart from the <script>.

Comment: This is assuming a `div#container` exists in your markup already. Also note that Javascript variables don't use `$`. Other than that, everything looks ready to do what you need it to :)

Comment: see my comment to thomas below :D

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working, its been about 4 hours working on it and I think I need to simplify my question so I can understand things better.  If you have a moment, I'd really appreciate if you could take a look at the reworded question.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: Thing is .. what you're asking to do (convert JSON to HTML) is what the function already does. Sounds like you're looking to get some extra functionality with Isotope.js going to complete your project. I **could** get it done for you, but its not what your question is asking. My email address is in my profile if you want help on your project. As is, the question here has been correctly answered. Two ways, if you count the jQuery implementation.

Comment: Hi Akamaozu - I have tried again, and still can't get it to work.  When I remove isotope from the equation, it does work (just like your fiddle), but if using isotope, it breaks and I get nothing back.  As you said, this question is about converting JSON to HTML, so I'll mark it as correct.  I will need to open another question to ask why isotope doesn't accept the code as is.  I really appreciate your help, thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. I've never worked with Isotope and I'm a little busy today but I'll check for your new question before I head to bed. If there's time (and it's unsolved) I'll do my best to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use more jQuery and less vanilla js you could do something like:

```
// document.ready shorhand
$(function() {
  var $container;

  // store destination element
  $container = $('#container');

  $.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {
    var items;

    // initialize array where we'll store html
    items = [];

    // loop through ajax response
    $.each(data, function() {
      var html;

      // build player html
      html = "<div class=\"players\" data-name=\"" + data.name + "\"> \
      <p class=\"score\">" + data.score + "</p> \
      <h3 class=\"name\">" + data.name + "</h3> \
      <p class=\"city\">" + data.city + "</p> \
      </div>"

      // add new html onto array
      items.push(html);
    });

    // squish all the html into a string
    items.join('');

    // set the html of the container to the html built above
    $container.html(items);
  });

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.players'
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks.  I am trying to learn JQuery as well so its nice to see it done both ways.  I'm still trying to work through both answers.  After modifying the css, apart from the <script> in the html body, do I need to put anything else in?

Comment: To use jQuery you'll need another <script> tag to include it. There would also need to be a <div id="container"></div> somewhere in the body of the page.

Comment: it might be because its late, but my brain isn't getting this.  Modifying the css (I'm trying to use the basic isotope css as a starting point) and incorporating this just isn't working!!!  Since I've also used a dummy JSON in the example above, translating it to use the actual JSON is driving me bonkers...but I really appreciate the help.  Want to make some $? :)

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working, its been about 4 hours working on it and I think I need to simplify my question so I can understand things better.  If you have a moment, I'd really appreciate if you could take a look at the reworded question.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: The one thing that is probably throwing you off (threw me off for a second) is that JSON is a string before it gets parsed, so it needs the quotes around it. Instead of sending it in raw like this `[{"name":"Hydrogen","number":1,"symbol":"H","weight":1.00794},{"name":"Helium","number":2,"symbol":"He","weight":4.002602},{"name":"Lithium","number":3,"symbol":"Li","weight":6.941}]` what you need is more like this `'[{"name":"Hydrogen","number":1,"symbol":"H","weight":1.00794},{"name":"Helium","number":2,"symbol":"He","weight":4.002602},{"name":"Lithium","number":3,"symbol":"Li","weight":6.941}]'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery tmpl plugin. It's not developed anymore, but it works really well.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Template defined in html

```
    <script id="myTmpl" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="player" data-name="${name}">
            <p class="score">${score}</p>
            <h3 class="name">${name}</h3>
            <p class="city">${city}</p>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Data pushed to the tmpl with jquery. Note: you don't need to cycle through data with a $.each or for: you can push the whole array and the tmpl plugin will handle it, pushing the data to the template for each entry of the array.

```
    $.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {
         var items = $('#mytmpl').tmpl(data);
         //items is your html object containing a div for each element of data.
         //you can push it to the dom through jQuery 
         //or $container.isotope( 'insert', items );
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Please ask further if it's not clear.