# Printing multi dimensional Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The code that sends the string looks like this, is it a json response perhaps?

```
    $.getJSON(loadUrl, parameters, function (response) {
        callback(response.data);
    })
```

Does this mean that the response indeed is json? See below screenshot for the actual response given (when using `alert(data)`):

[image]

EDIT:
I think that the returned data is indeed json. This is what the console looks like when printing the data returend:
[image]

EDIT2:

The response was indeed json. I looped it like below:

```
$(data).each(function(index, element){  
$('#scores').append('<tr><td> '+element[0]+' </td> <td> '+element[1]+' </td></tr>');       
    })
```

Comment: Split by commas, take one for the title, take the next for the number, output row, repeat.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the question is. I can't see any reference to HTML table in the question...

Comment: @JakubKonecki I see your point. Couldn't think of a better title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string as you done before and convert it to jSon object.
Then you can create table from it easily..

ref : [jQuery function to create table using JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803171/jquery-function-to-create-table-using-json-data)

Comment: have a look to fiddler link provided in above post

Comment: The example in the link worked.

Answer (score 1):

As deceze said you should split the string by commas

```
var str="/startpage,147,/contact,97";
var n=str.split(","); //['/startpage','147',/contact','97' ]
```

Then loop the array to create the html

```
for(i=0; i < n.length; i+=2)
{
  var title = n[i];
  var value = n[i+1];
}
```

Please be aware this is a very dirty solution. If you have control over the string's origin, you should consider changing to another format, such as JSON or XML

Comment: I've updated the post, some of the code handling the response is calling json.