# How i can generate table from json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm newbie in javascript,

i look from this answer [jQuery function to create table using JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803171/jquery-function-to-create-table-using-json-data)

but, i have another dataset, we can call it data2

```
var data2 = [
 {
  "key" : "Quantity" ,
  "bar": true,
  "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0] ]
 } ,
 {
  "key" : "Price" ,
  "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 71.89] ]
 }
]
```

i have tried tu modify the code, like this :

```
$(data2.Quantity).each(function(index, element){
     $('#table1').append('<tr><td> '+element[0]+' </td> <td> '+element[1]+' </td>   </tr>');       
})
```

but table still can't generate from data2 (i want to generate table each key (Quantity, Price)

my full code in here http://jsfiddle.net/kVdZG/493/

How i can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean by generate table each key something like this:-

<tr><td>Quantity</td></tr>
<tr><td>Price</td></tr>

Comment: Yeah right, it's what i mean

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/duwds/

Comment: `$(data2.Quantity).each(...)` assumes that `data2.Quantity` both exists and [is a JQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/each/). Unfortunately, neither of those details are true. `data2` is an array, which means you cannot (by default) access values from it without iterating across it. You should look at using the other [`jQuery.each` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are looping through your array, you have data which is a key-value pair. You need to loop through each element in that array and, if that key is the desired one, select its values.

Keys in javascript are called by `element.key`.

The values are stored in the "values" key in `data2`.

```
$(data2).each(function(index, element){
    if(element.key == "Quantity")
        $('#table1').append('<tr><td> '+element.values[0]+' </td> <td> '+element.values[1]+' </td></tr>'); 
});
```

You are also specifying a two-dimensional array, which is why calling only `[0]` will not work. You would need to change it to `[0][i]` where `i` is the element in the loop.

```
$(data2).each(function(index, element){
    if(element.key == "Quantity") {
        for(i=0; i<element.values.length; i++) {
            $('#table1').append('<tr><td> '+element.values[i][0]+' </td> <td> '+element.values[i][1]+' </td></tr>');
        }
    }
});
```

[Updated working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVdZG/497/).

Complete code:

```
var data = { "scores" : [ ["3/1/2011", 610],["4/1/2011", 610],["5/1/2011", 610],["6/1/2011", 610], ["7/1/2011", 720], ["8/1/2011", 500], ["9/1/2011", 500] ] }


var data2 = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0]
  } ,
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
    "values" : [ 1136005200000 , 71.89]
  }
]

$(data.scores).each(function(index, element){
     $('#scores').append('<tr><td> '+element[0]+' </td> <td> '+element[1]+' </td></tr>');       
});


$(data2).each(function(index, element){
    if(element.key == "Quantity") {
        for(i=0; i<element.values.length; i++) {
            $('#table1').append('<tr><td> '+element.values[i][0]+' </td> <td> '+element.values[i][1]+' </td></tr>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: wow, thanks! it's work...but when i want to add some values, example i have modify this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kVdZG/496/, the table it's wrong, i want to make each values in one row, how i can do that ? thx

Comment: I think you want to use a loop for that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:-

Javascript

```
 data2.forEach(function(obj){
    $('#table1').append('<tr><td> '+obj["key"]+' </td></tr>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but feel free to correct me. I have created a div with tables in it per value in your data2. Also, data2 seemed to have some incorrect structure so my "corrected" structure is:

```
var data2 = [{
    "key": "Quantity",
    "bar": true,
    "values": [1136005200000, 1271000.0]
}, {
    "key": "Price",
    "values": [1136005200000, 71.89]
}]
```

The javascript to achieve the tables are:

```
$(data2).each(function (index, element) {
    var tableId = 'table' + index;
    var tableContainer = $('#tableContainer').append('<table border="2" id="' + tableId + '"><tr><td> ' + element.key + ' </td> <td> </td></tr></table>');
    var table = tableContainer.find('#' + tableId);
    $(element.values).each(function (i, value) {
        table.append('<tr><td> ' + value + ' </td> <td> </td></tr>');
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/kVdZG/494/